# QProcess not emitting its signals when not waitForFinished()

Tags: c++, qt

In the following code omitting the `waitForFinished()` makes the QProcess stop emitting its signal. What the heck is wrong with it? Is this a Qt Bug? (5.7). Note this code is run parallel with QtConcurrent run. But this should not change anything, should it? Afaik sending signals in other threads is fine, though they will be queued.

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);

connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [](){
    qDebug()<< "readyReadStandardOutput";
});

connect(process, &QProcess::stateChanged, [](QProcess::ProcessState state){
    qDebug()<< "stateChanged"<< state;
});

connect(process, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
    [=](){
    qDebug()<< "finsished";
});

connect(process, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
    [this, process](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
    qDebug()<< "finsished";
    if (exitStatus == QProcess::NormalExit && exitCode == 0){
        while (process->canReadLine()) {
           QString line = QString::fromLocal8Bit(process->readLine());
           QRegularExpression regex("\"(.*)\" {(.*)}");
           QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(line);
           names_.push_back(match.captured(1));
           uuids_.push_back(match.captured(2));
        }
    }
    process->deleteLater();
});
process->start("VBoxManage",  {"list", "vms"});
process->waitForFinished(); // This line changes everything
qDebug()<< "leftWaitForFinished";
```

Comment: do you have alll this code inside a lambda function that is passed to `QtConcurrent::run`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not running an event loop in the thread where the `QProcess` instance lives. Any `QObject` in a thread without an event loop is only partially functional - timers won't run, queued calls won't be delivered, etc. So you can't do that. Using `QObject`s with `QtConcurrent::run` requires care.

At the very least, you should have a temporary event loop for as long as the process lives - in that case you should hold `QProcess` by value, since `deleteLater` won't be executed after the event loop has quit.

```
QProcess process;
...
QEventLoop loop;
connect(process, &QProcess::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();
```

Otherwise, you need to keep the process in a more durable thread, and keep that thread handle (`QThread` is but a handle!) in a thread that has an event loop that can dispose of it when it's done.

```
// This can be run from a lambda that runs in an arbitrary thread

auto thread = new QThread;
auto process = new QProcess;

...

connect(process, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
    [this, process](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
    ...
    process->deleteLater();
    process->thread()->quit();
});

process->start("VBoxManage",  {"list", "vms"});
process->moveToThread(thread);

// Move the thread **handle** to the main thread
thread->moveToThread(qApp->thread());
connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);
thread->start();
```

Alas, this is very silly since you're creating temporary threads and that's expensive and wasteful. You should have *one* additional worker thread where you take care of all low-overhead work such as `QProcess` interaction. That thread should always be running, and you can move all `QProcess` and similar object instances to it, from concurrent lambdas etc.

Comment: There are multiple jobs like this that have to be done. I use Concurrent because this way I can easily use all cores. However, why exactly does it not work? Is it the lambda? The object I call run on is in the main thread. Will making the lambda a member function work?

Comment: sorry as this may sound stupid, but aren't threads from `QThreadPool` already running an event loop? (in order to execute functions that are passed to `QThreadPool::start` for instance)

Comment: I've said exactly why it doesn't work: it's because for a `QObject` like a `QProcess` to be functional, the thread it runs on must run an event loop! It has **nothing** to do with lambdas or anything like that. The object where you call `run` is irrelevant: the lambda runs in a worker thread where there's no event loop.

Comment: No, the threads from the event pool are *not* running an event loop. Event loops are comparatively high-latency because they interoperate with operating system event queues. The `QThreadPool` uses faster, direct mechanisms like mutexes/semaphores. The jobs you submit to `QThreadPool` can be very short, on the order of 0.01ms-0.1ms - it must have very low overhead when presented with such jobs, and the event loop wouldn't cut it generally speaking.

Comment: thanks @KubaOber , I expected that after reading your answer, just wanted to make sure. . .